# Lag() function with WHERE clause

Tags: mysql, sql, subquery, where-clause, window-functions

I have this sql function that works properly:

```
SELECT out_hum ,
 (out_hum - LAG(out_hum, 1) OVER (ORDER BY id)) As dif
FROM excel_table
```

But I want to select all the out_hum when the diferrence (dif) is equal to 0 or grater than a value. When I type this code I get an error...

```
SELECT out_hum ,
 (out_hum - LAG(out_hum, 1) OVER (ORDER BY id)) As dif
FROM excel_table  WHERE dif=0
```

How I can solve this?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The `where` clause cannot access aliases to expressions defined in the `select` clause (because, basically, the former is processed *before* the latter). On top of that, there is a special restriction to window functions, which can not appear in the `where` clause of a query (they are allowed only in the `select` and `order by` clauses).

Some databases support the `qualify` clause, which works around the language limitation - but not MySQL unfortunately. A typical solution is to use a derived table, such as a subquery:

```
select *
from (
    select out_hum, out_hum - lag(out_hum) over (order by id) as dif
    from excel_table
) t
where dif = 0
```

Notes:

- parenthesis around the substraction are not necessary
- `1` is the default value of the second argument of `lag()`, so there is no need to specify it