# How do you call previous row in a where clause?

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

I am trying to figure out how to get rid of results that occur close together.  For example the rows have a create timestamp (source_time).  I want to remove results that occur within 10 seconds of each other.

I thought lag() might do it, but I can't use that in the where clause.

```
select *
from table
where source_time - previous(source_time) >= 10 second
```

Very rough code, but I am not sure how to call the previous source time.  I have translated them to timestamps and used timestamp_diff(source_time, x, second) >= 10 but not sure how to make x the previous value.

Hopefully this is clear.

Comment: Looking here ... https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61879104/lag-function-with-where-clause this seems to give a good clue.  It looks like you could create a derived table which is composed of your original table plus an extra column (eg. one called dif) that contains the difference from the last logical entry.  From there you can execute a where using that derived column.  If that isn't clear, post some sample data and expected results.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this with subqueries.

```
delete table t1
where t1.id in (
  select t2.id
  from (
    select
      id,
      source_time - lag(source_time) over (order by source_time) as time_diff
    from table
  ) t2
  where t2.time_diff < 10 second
)
```

Keep in mind this can potentially leave large gaps in your records if. For example, if you get a row every 9 seconds for an hour you'll delete all but the last record in that hour.

You might instead partition the source_time every 10 seconds and delete anything with a row_number > 1.

```
delete table t1
where t1.id in (
  select t2.id
  from (
    select
      id,
      source_time,
      row_number() over(
        partition by source_time - make_interval(second => extract(second from source_time) % 10)
        order by source_time asc
      ) rownum
    from table
  ) t2
  where rownum > 1
)
```

Comment: Thank you for the reply, maybe if I add a bit more context it will help clarify what might be the better way.  I am trying to get rid of instances where a customer (customer_id) might accidently put something in their cart and then remove it.  The source_time is the time that the item got put into the cart, but there isn't anything to join on that says an item was removed from the cart.  Basically trying to say if something stayed in the cart for less than 10 seconds it wasn't supposed to go in at all.